# calculating tf-idf for web pages

Tags: information-retrieval, tf-idf

I am new to IR and I would like to calculate tf-idf for webpages.

For the "tf" part, I want to calculate see frequency of each word in content of one webpage.

For the "idf" part, I want to compare multiple webpages for the content.

Is there a tool/API that can help with this? Any platform is ok. And could someone explain how can I fulfill this?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to index a collection of Web pages first using tools such as [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/). These indexing frameworks would create two things for you... first is an **inverted index**, i.e., a list of documents in which a term occurs in (analogous to the index of a book where for each important term a list is stored which indicates in which pages these terms occur)... this takes care of the tf part... the second is the **collection statistics** which stores global (not per-document) statistics, such as document frequency (in how many documents does
a term occur) etc.

These two files are then used during the retrieval stage to return a list of top ranked documents. Here's a nice [tutorial](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/) on Lucene which should help you get started. Particularly useful are the classes **IndexWriter**, **StandardAnalyzer**, **Document**, **IndexSearcher** and **BM25Similarity**.